# How to exclude rows with duplicate columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have the following data:

```
id1   id2    data
----------------------
7     8      test1
7     8      test2
8     7      test1
8     7      test2
```

For my needs id1 and id2 can be transposed, so this is essentially duplicate data.  How can I select only one combination of id1/id2 and all of their unique values for `data`?  So desired output would be:

```
7   8   test1
7   8   test2
```

or

```
8   7   test1
8   7   test2
```

It really doesn't matter which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if really all records are duplicated this way and `id1!=id2`, could this work?

```
select distinct id1, id2, data from test where id1 < id2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you records are not duplicated, you can do:

```
select distinct (case when id1 < id2 then id1 else id2 end) as idlow,
       (case when id1 < id2 then id2 else id1 end) as idhigh,
       data
from table t
```